# Full viewport height image with parallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I wish for certain sections of a page to fill out **at least 100% of the viewport height** regardless of the screen size. I also want the content and background of sections to **scroll with a parallax effect**.

I have jQuery on the page and use the following to resize the section `.parallax` to full viewport height:

```
var imageFit = function() {
  windowHeight = $(window).height();
  $('.parallax').css('min-height', windowHeight);
};

$(document).ready(imageFit);
$(window).resize(imageFit);
```

I'm aware of the units `vh` and `vw` but I don't want to use them because of poor browser support. *(By the way, I'm really bad at javascript so please help me improve this if possible).*

---

**Here's a pen with the 100% viewport height section: http://codepen.io/Mest/full/GpycL** *(If unfamiliar with Codepen; click Edit in the bottom left corner to edit the code).*

This works fine, however I'm not how  to implement the parallax effect. I've tried using [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to modify CSS properties in order to create the parallax effect. However since my `section` gets it's full viewport height `height`-value from the script above it seems like Skrollr doesn't consider it to have any height and thus makes the parallax "transition" to occur instantly as I scroll. It works great without the resizing script above.

Sadly I'm unable to set up an example with Skrollr for you, but I confirmed this is what happens by giving my section a height value of *X* px in my CSS and then Skrollr functioned as it should while scrolling for the first *X* px.

### Thus, my question is the following:

How can I make Skrollr recognize the `height` set by the script above?

or,

Is there a better/easier way to create the effect I want? Either through another scrolling animation library or with a different approach to fill out the viewport height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to call [`refresh()`](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#refreshelements) at the end of `imageFit`.

If you include https://gist.github.com/Prinzhorn/5796546 as well, it would be as simple as

```
var imageFit = function() {
   windowHeight = $(window).height();
   $('.parallax').css('min-height', windowHeight).refresh();
};
```

Comment: It truly was that simple, nice! Is it implied by the script to only refresh `.parallax` and not every element in the document? Thank you for Skrollr, by the way, it seems to be right down my alley. :-)

Comment: @NilsKaspersson "Is it implied by the script to only refresh .parallax and not every element in the document". What do you mean by that? The `refresh` jQuery helper will only refresh the selected elements (`.parallax`).

Comment: You answered my question. I don't know a whole lot about javascript. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: I might have been too fast to say this was solved; it seems like this solved parallax absolute mode but the problem persists in relative mode. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe create a new question and include an example.